# schedule PeriodicTask at 6am everyday Android

Tags: android

I want to run a Job Service everyday daily at 6:00 AM in the morning and do some work. since i can only set `setPeriod` i could not able to figure out a way to execute or reschedule the task everyday at 6AM. Thanks in advance.

```
    private static long periodSecs = 7200L; //TODO: Set 6AM everyday
    private static final String JOB_TAG = "NOTIFICATION_JOB";

    private void scheduleJob() {
        Timber.i("scheduleJob");
        Task task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
                .setService(Job.class)
                .setPeriod(periodSecs)
                .setTag(JOB_TAG)
                .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build();

        GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this).schedule(task);
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using an alarm manager or job scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

AlaraManager perform your task periodically for you.
use it like this way.

```
    public void scheduleAlarm(View v)
    {
        //set time here
        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+24*60*60*1000;

        // Create an Intent and set the class that will execute when the Alarm triggers.         
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

       // onReceive() method of this class will execute when the broadcast from your alarm is received.

        // Get the Alarm Service
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Set the alarm for a particular time.
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for Tommrrow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
    }
```

**AlarmReceiver Class**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {

       //perform what ever the operation you want 
      //when alarm triggers daily on your time 

     }
}
```

Comment: you can also do this using TimerTask ,but it does not work properly in some devices and get killed after some time by system if require space.